# Running classification to pixels that corresponds to training data only

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification

When I run my code to conduct a crop type classification over my stacked layer, the whole stacked layer is classified to the three crops I provided in my training, which is not the true ground case.

How can i adjust this code to classify parts of the stacked layer that correspond to my training data and leave the pixels that not corresponding to blank?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8cef2ca0a0e1f25dbd3fa5b303a68443

```
          ////////////////////TrainingData////////////
var referenceData = ee.Image().byte()
                  .paint(Rice, 0)
                  .paint(Maize, 1)
                  .paint(cotton,2)
                  .rename("class");

var training = stacked.float().addBands(referenceData).stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 0,
  classBand: "class",
  region: Delta,
  scale: 30,
  projection: stacked.select(0).projection(),
  classValues: [0,1,2],
  classPoints: [1000,1000,1000]
})

// //How balanced are the training data?
// //print(training.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), ["class"]));
Map.addLayer(training,{},'training_sample',false);

// Filter out the null property values and try again.

var sample=training.randomColumn();
var split=0.7
var training_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split));
var validation_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split));

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
    numberOfTrees: 128,
    minLeafPopulation: 4
  })
  .train({
    features: training_sample,
    classProperty: 'class',
    inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),
  })



var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified');

Map.addLayer(classified.randomVisualizer(),{},'classification', false);


// // Classify the validation data.
var validated = validation_sample.classify(classifier);

var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('class', 'classification');
print('Test overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Test kappa accuracy: ', testAccuracy.kappa());
print('Training producer accuracy: ', testAccuracy.producersAccuracy());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "classify parts of the stacked layer that correspond to my training data and leave the pixels that not corresponding to blank"?